# MatCalendar: using DateRange but range is not displayed, selectChange fires Date instead of DateRange

Tags: angular-material2

What are you trying to do?

implementing a date range picker dialog with the calendar component

What troubleshooting steps have you tried?

range is not previewed/displayed, change event returns Date object

Reproduction

We can only help if we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-wsgnr4?file=src/app/example-component.html

Environment

- Angular: 10.0.3
- CDK/Material: 10.0.1
- Browser(s): Chrome
- Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has been solved here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20307 :)
needed to instantiate a new class `new DateRange(start, end)` instead of `<DateRange<Date>>{start, end}`